# RVM keeps adding a directory to my PATH and then throws a warning that PATH isn't set up correctly

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, command-line-interface

I know there's a lot of other questions out there addressing this issue, but I haven't been able to find anything solution that works for me, so I'm posting in case I've missed something.

Using the command-line, when I `cd` into a Rails site directory, RVM changes my path by adding "Users/username/bin" to the front of the PATH variable and then it throws a warning about how PATH is not set up correctly because because the ruby gems version isn't in first place in PATH.

Here's my $PATH output prior to changing into a ROR directory:

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby- 2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby2.1.1/bin:/Users/username/.nvm/v0.10.18/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/munki:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin
```

And after changing the directory into a ROR directory:

```
/Users/username/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@rorproject/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/username/.rvm/bin:/Users/username/.nvm/v0.10.18/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/munki
```

I realize that RVM is supposed to change the PATH variable, but why is it adding the "Users/username/bin" to the front?

Here's my .bashrc file:

```
[[ -s /Users/username/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . /Users/username/.nvm/nvm.sh # This loads NVM

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Here's my .profile file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

And .bash_profile file:

```
source ~/.profile

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  source ~/.bashrc
fi

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Things I've tried are:

- `rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles`
- `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles`
- `rvm use 2.1.1`
- removing RVM completely and reinstalling
- removing the Rails site directory and re-cloning from github
- resetting PATH

I've deleted my .profile file and removed the "source ~/.profile" from .bash_profile per 7stud and still the same result (I've closed down iterm and reopened it as well).

.ruby-gemset file:

```
rorproject
```

.ruby-version file:

```
2.1.1
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://rails-assets.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'unicorn-rails'
gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.8.0"
gem 'foreman'
gem 'sorcery', github: 'NoamB/sorcery'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'date_validator', github: 'codegram/date_validator'
gem 'oj'                  # faster json handling
#gem 'oj_mimic_json'       # for OJ integration w/ ROR 4.1+
gem 'rails-patch-json-encode' # for OJ integration w/ ROR < 4.1
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'haml-rails'          # Used by the frontend app, via grunt, and for PDF generation
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'state_machine'

gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'

# Attachment handling
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'mime-types'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'unf'
gem 'mini_magick'

# PDF Calendars
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'wicked_pdf'

# Excel output
gem 'axlsx_rails'

# Exception reporting
gem "sentry-raven"

# Soft deletes
gem 'paranoia', '~> 2.0'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use debugger
group :development, :test do
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', :github => 'sporkrb/spork-rails'

  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-process'
  gem 'guard-migrate', :github => 'glanotte/guard-migrate'

  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', :require => false
  gem 'faker'
end

group :development do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'  # Do the require in dev, so rails generators can make factories
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'

  gem 'simplecov',      :require => false
  gem 'simplecov-rcov', :require => false
end
```

I do not have an .rvmrc file nor a .versions.conf file.

I'm at a complete loss and any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be something with nvm, maybe both are acting on your path when you change directories?

Comment: I have that same nvm line in my files, and rvm works correctly for me, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: I have both NVM and RVM on another computer and I don't get the warning there either

Comment: I will add that the only things in the mystery directory of Users/username/bin are vi, vim, and mvim symlinks. Not sure if that helps at all

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of your .profile file.  Delete it.
2. Delete the line in .bash_profile: `source ~/.profile`

If that doesn't help, please post your Gemfile and the .rvmrc file in your project's directory(if present) and/or .ruby-version, .ruby-gemset, .versions.conf.

Response to comment:

I would try deleting your two files: .ruby-gemset and .ruby-version, then in your Gemfile use these lines:

```
ruby '2.1.1'
#ruby-gemset=rorproject
```

They really should do the same thing, but let's see.

Comment: I've edited the post to include those files you've listed. Removing .profile and the "source ~/.profile" line didn't change the result.

Comment: @CommodoreTimo, see my additional suggestion in my post.